# Linux (zip): how to find all files that are not readable?

Tags: linux, terminal, server, zip, admin

I just tried to **zip** folder and it's content by this command:

```
zip -r ./mytarget.zip ./mysource
```

At the end I got the **warning**:

```
zip warning: Not all files were readable
files/entries read:  141595 (4.2G bytes)  skipped:  57 (1.8M bytes)
```

I'd like to know **which files were skipped**.

How can I find **all the files that were not readable?** I don't have `sudo` rights on that server.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @jww It's part of a script, so kind of in the middle of Stackoverflow and Super User.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you can use

```
find . ! -readable
```

to recursively scan for unreadable files or directories. This command takes into account permissions, but also broken links.

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't show any files. The files were probably blocked by something else, because the zipping was successfully a few tries later.

Answer (score 8):

I experienced the same as you, and `find . ! -readable` didn't help.

I solved it by logging all output from the zip command to a file:

```
 zip -r my-archive.zip /path/to/dir/ &>> zip-log
```

and then searching in it for the `warning` word, which did not only occured at the end of the command's output, as a summary, but also just after each of the files causing trouble (2 in my case):

```
  adding: home/myuser/.cagefs/tmp/mysql.sock
    zip warning: could not open for reading: home/myuser/.cagefs/tmp/mysql.sock
  adding: home/myuser/.cagefs/tmp/lshttpd/ (stored 0%)
  adding: home/myuser/.cagefs/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432
    zip warning: could not open for reading: home/myuser/.cagefs/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432
```

Answer (score 0):

I fix this by updating the zip package and clear all the cache, here is the step :

- delete the previous zip (which failed)
- sudo apt-get update
- sudo apt-get upgrade
- clear & purge all the cache from web dashboard and cloudflare
- reboot the server
- try zip these files